# Creating Tabs in Phonegap

Tags: cordova, mobile, mobile-application, phonegap-4.0.0

I am trying to create a mobile application. I would just like to ask how to  create tabs in Phonegap. Like the fixed navigation bar at the bottom. If there are no solution, how to create a fixed/header footer and maintain it in all pages? Thank you.

Comment: are you using phonegap or ionic ?

Comment: I chose to use Phonegap because for me, it's simpler. Ionic uses Angular and typescript which I am not familiar with so I chose to stick with Phonegap

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to scroll the area above the footer, iScroll is worth looking at:

https://cubiq.org/iscroll

And this is the example of sample application in Phonegap with tabs in footer.

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/phonegap-from-scratch-app-template--mobile-9373

Comment: did you check this ?